# Enable GitLab to display error

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed an omnibus GitLab package on my linux machine, and i try to configure it. Everytime i have a page "ERROR 500, Whoops, something went wrong on our end.". I don't have `root` access and looking at the log files is very compelling for my team and me.

Do you know if it's possible to definitively enable displaying errors directly in web page ?

I looked for a configuration variable in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file, but nothing found.